# Get all leaf elemnts of a tree using mysql

Tags: mysql, optimization, recursion, query-optimization

This is my first post on this blog please help me

I am trying to get all the last element from a recursive query but it is taking to much time to proceed is there a better way to do this what I exactly doing is

Suppose I have a table like

```
ID      ParentId
1       0
2       1
3       1
4       1
5       2
6       2
7       3
8       4
```

For Id 1 I want to get 5,6,7,8 as out put for you can see that parents of 5,6,7,8 are children of 1 similarly for Id 2 o/p must be 5 and 6 Is there an optimum solution for that. I mean some thing else than running a query repeatedly to get the child elements

---

What I did to solve the issue in MySQL was I added an additional field "allParent" which contained comma separated ID's of current category I my example the table now would have been

```
ID      ParentID      allParent
1       0             0
2       1             0,1
3       1             0,1
4       1             0,1
5       2             0,1,2
6       2             0,1,2
7       3             0,1,3
8       4             0,1,4
```

Now the query to fetch all leaf level entities would be

```
Select * from table where (
    allParent LIKE '1,%' or 
    allParent LIKE ',1%' or 
    allParent LIKE '%,1,%'
) and ID NOT IN (
    Select ParentId from table where
    allParent LIKE '1,%' or 
    allParent LIKE ',1%' or 
    allParent LIKE '%,1,%'
)
```

And this Worked for me

Comment: I would try to get all elements that ID is not present in ParentId column in any record of this table (I hope you understand what I want to say :P ).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

Comment: well but I want to get result from a specific level for example what if I want to get leaf nodes element having parentId = 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Mysql you cann not get this kind of select.

In Oracle is possible.

The only way to do it in this specific case is to nest left joins as number of levels you have.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using MySQL, your best bet would be to use a [closure table](http://karwin.blogspot.com/2010/03/rendering-trees-with-closure-tables.html).  If you are using a different database (ex: PostgreSQL), you can likely do recursive queries, allowing the database to handle the recursion instead of your code.